# Numerically stable average of java.util.Dates

Tags: java, numerical-stability

I've got a bunch of Dates and I want to find their average.

- How many Dates within 100 years of now can I sum before I run into overflow problems?  Any gotchas?
- What's the best way to calculate the average, avoiding overflow problems?

Comment: With what type of primitive do you want to sum the dates? Are you storing them as ms from 1/1/1970?

Comment: This is straightforward algebra: if you're computing the sum with e.g. a 64-bit type, then you can hold values up to 2^63-1.  Divide that by the maximum value you're interested in, and that tells you how many you can sum together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.out.println(Long.MAX_VALUE / System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Output:

```
6892653
```

I think this answers both of your questions. You can also divide each epoch value by 1000*60*60*24, but given the size of that raw quotient, even that's probably overkill.

Comment: The denominator should probably be (System.currentTimeMillis() + (100 * 365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)), given that he wants dates within a hundred years. That comes out around 2052416 - fewer than a third as many, but still quite a few.

Comment: @TomAnderson Yes, we're now 42 years into the epoch, and OP needs up to 142 yrs. I had that in mind, but as soon as I saw the magnitude of the quotient, I didn't bother with it.